# Rust: Strange state-based rounding behaviour on f32

Tags: rust, rounding-error

When computing the dot-product of two `nalgebra::Vector3` structs using specific values, I get the following behaviour ([link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0697d3a858808aef736a198e581aeebf)):

```
use nalgebra::{Point3, Vector3}; // 0.31.0

fn dot(v1: Vector3<f32>, v2: Vector3<f32>) -> f32 {
    v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y + v1.z * v2.z
    
}

fn main() {
    println!("Run 1:");
    let u = Vector3::new(1000., -1000., 0.);
    let v = Vector3::new(-0.69294637441651, 0.720989108085632, 0.);
    println!(
        "self-written dot-product: \t{:.32}",
        dot(u, v)
    );
    println!(
        "nalgebra dot-product: \t\t{:.32}",
        u.dot(&v)
    );
    println!("\nRun2:");
    let u = Vector3::new(1000., -1000., 0.);
    let v = Vector3::new(-0.69294637441651, 0.720989108085632, 0.);
    println!(
        "nalgebra dot-product: \t\t{:.32}",
        u.dot(&v)
    );
}
```

Output:

```
Run 1:
self-written dot-product:   -1413.93554687500000000000000000000000
nalgebra dot-product:       -1413.93554687500000000000000000000000
Run2:
nalgebra dot-product:       -1413.93548250214189465623348951339722
```

I must be able to rely on the computation to always be the same. Any thoughts?

Related to my previous question, which I closed due to non-working examples [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72772931/rust-vs-delphi-different-numeric-results-based-on-32bit-floating-point)

Comment: It's not state. In the second case, the compiler decides to use f64. In the first case, it's forced to be f32 since your function explicitly expects it.

Comment: Oh right. Thanks! That solves the puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @aedm has mentioned in the comment, your `dot()` function is the cause for this behavior. As a beginner rustacean it wasn't quite obvious to me how it is exactly a cause, so I put an explanation here.

When you define variables for the first time,

```
 9| println!("Run 1:");
10| let u = Vector3::new(1000., -1000., 0.);
11| let v = Vector3::new(-0.69294637441651, 0.720989108085632, 0.);
```

Rust compiler doesn't know exact type of the values, it only understands that it's `float`. And if there would be no extra information, the compiler would fall for `f64` as a [default float type in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#floating-point-types).

When you call `dot(u, v)` - you're letting the compiler know the exact types because you specified them on function declaration:

```
 3| fn dot(v1: Vector3<f32>, v2: Vector3<f32>) -> f32 {
```

The compiler is now certain that the values of `u` and `v` are of a type `f32`.

Then you're using `.dot()` method, which can handle both `f32` and `f64`. The type of `u` and `v` is already defined as `f32`, and the type of variables cannot be changed, but cause `.dot()` can handle `f32`, it makes the compiler happy. At this point you get:

```
Run 1:
-1413.93554687500000000000000000000000
-1413.93554687500000000000000000000000
```

After that you're defining new variables with the same names - again the compiler has no explicit information about the type of the variables. But this time there's no `dot(u, v)` call, only `.dot()` and the latter one doesn't require `f32`, so the compiler goes for the default `f64`. In the end you get:

```
Run2:
-1413.93548250214189465623348951339722
```